# Unity codeless IAP

Tags: unity, android, in-app-purchase

So I'm trying the "new" codeless IAP. I followed the instructions exactly. On my old testing device I'm getting purchase Failed : Duplicate transaction. This is expected because the product is a NonConsumable and I have already purchased it. But on a fresh new device with the exact same build I'm getting a message in the google play pop up : The selected product is unavailable( note I'm translating the message bacause it returns it in Bulgarian, so the exact text may not be the same but the meaning is). Has anyone encountered this ?

Comment: It used to be that IAP didn't work on Google play unless you had the version you're testing up as a beta build. We're not doing that on Knightfall and it's still working, so this may have changed. But that was the issue we had on Love & Hip Hop.

Answer (score 1):

> To test the IAP, make a purchase on a device logged in with an Alpha Tester Google Account. A modified purchase dialog box appears to confirm the fact this product is under test and is free.

Source: [Test IAP Details](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityIAPGoogleConfiguration.html)